# Disable higlighting selected items in QListWidget pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, highlight, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

How do I disable higlighting selected items in `QListWidget` pyqt5?

Tried the following which didn't work:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QGridLayout, QLabel, QWidget

app = QApplication([])
widget = QWidget()
listWidget = QListWidget()
item = QListWidgetItem('Pogba', listWidget)
layout.addWidget(listWidget)

#Attempt
palette = QPalette()
palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, listWidget.palette().color(QPalette.Base))
palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, listWidget.palette().color(QPalette.Text))
listWidget.setPalette(palette)

widget.setLayout(layout)
widget.show()
app.exec()
```

And the following only makes the item grey instead of blue:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QGridLayout, QLabel, QWidget

app = QApplication([])
widget = QWidget()
listWidget = QListWidget()
item = QListWidgetItem('Pogba', listWidget)
layout.addWidget(listWidget)

#Other attempt
listWidget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

widget.setLayout(layout)
widget.show()
app.exec()
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to visually distinguish items that are selected and items that are not? If that's so, I'd say that it would be a very bad choice. Can you clarify the reasons behind it?

Comment: Yes. U remember that soccer line-up app I'm making? I'm only using the listWidget to drag players out of.

Comment: The palette approach should work, what OS are you using? Besides that, what's the point of the QLabel?

Comment: Windows 10. Sorry, that's unnecessary.

Comment: I cannot test on that environment, but using the default windows style it should work with the palette. Can you reproduce the issue with your given code (provided the unnecessary label code is removed)?

Comment: U just want me to remove the label code?